# How to change the input source name in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, input-languages

I'm talking about this:

[image: Preferences - Language & Text]

I'd like "Romanian - Standard" to be just "Romanian". There's already an entry called Romanian, but I can't use it with my keyboard layout.

Does anyone know a way, even hackish, to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system-supplied keyboard layouts are located in `/System/Library/Keyboard Layouts/AppleKeyBoardLayouts.bundle`.

Right-click that bundle and select *Show Package Contents*.

Navigate to `Contents/Resources/English.lproj/`

---

Edit the `InfoPlist.strings` file to change the names used for the keyboard layouts in your English locale. The left side is the internal name of the layout -- don't change that -- and the right side is the localized name.

```
"Romanian" = "Romanian";
"Romanian-Standard" = "Romanian - Standard";
```

I changed it to the following:

```
"Romanian" = "Romanian - Nonstandard";
"Romanian-Standard" = "Romanian";
```

To be able to edit these files, you need to add your user account to the list of authorized users in the `English.lproj` folder's *Get Info* dialog (read/write permissions), as well as the `InfoPlist.strings` file itself (also read/write privileges).

Save, close, and check *System Preferences* to see if it worked.

It did for me:

[image]